# How to return JSON in Pascal Case in Azure Functions (v2)?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have this Function

```
[FunctionName("json")]
public static JsonResult json
(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, new string[] { "POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PATCH", "PUT" })]
        HttpRequest req,
        TraceWriter log
)
{
    return new JsonResult(new
    {
        Nome = "TONY",
        Metodo = req.Method.ToString()
    });
}
```

the problem is that it is returning

```
{"nome":"TONY","metodo":"GET"}
```

I want it to return

```
{"Nome":"TONY","Metodo":"GET"}
```

In ASP.Net Core 2 I used this:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver());
// Keep the Case as is
```

**How to configure Azure Functions to do that way?**

Answer (score 5):

you could do something like this:

```
[FunctionName("json")]
    public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            RequestMessage = req,
            Content = new StringContent(
                content: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    Nome = "TONY",
                    Metodo = req.Method.ToString()
                }),
                encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                mediaType: "application/json")
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the JsonPropertyAttribute to the properties and include Json.NET via #r "Newtonsoft.Json" at the top of the file.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

And decorate the properties

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "nome" )]
public string Nome { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "metodo" )]
public string Metodo { get; set; }
```